# Running GISquirrel next to ArcSDE?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server

My company has ArcSDE to run our webmapping system.  We want our ArcGIS for Desktop Basic license users to be able to edit this data without dropping 30k for 6 users on upgrading to standard.

Can we run [GISquirrel](https://www.gisquirrel.com/) next to ArcSDE to edit the same database?

I'm assuming we can't, but wanted to be sure.

I'm using SQL server 2008.

Comment: Data is not stored in ArcSDE, it's stored in a database, and accessed by ArcGIS *through* ArcSDE.  Please update your question to include which RDBMS software you are using.

Comment: Is your "webmapping system" based on an ArcGIS for Server Standard level license or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Also it isn't 30K to upgrade to standard, unless your talking about ArcGIS Server "Standard"? GIS Squirrel works with your database. Which database are you using SQL Server? It's a good product for bypassing the license issues. To answer your question, yes you can edit! It's only $5500 more to add a standard license of ArcGIS Desktop FYI.

Comment: How would it work if a webmapping server was reading the database all the time.  Would it update after the user saved and unlocked it.  I'm assuming the locking only keeps people from editing and not reading the database.

Comment: Transactional databases don't have locks (that something ArcSDE has to simulate).  I make database INSERTs, UPDATEs and DELETEs all the time, and they're immediately reflected in maps, but you can't use any of the features that ArcSDE provides (versioning, archives, logfiles, locks,... *or* SDEBINARY storage) without setting yourself up for a major dose of FUBAR.